# Касперский и автономные файлы

Tags: windows, kaspersky, offline

Если вкратце - установка Касперского ломает механизм автономных файлов.
Более подробно.
ОС на станции - Windows 10 x64 Pro 21H2. Машина в домене, профиль перенаправляется на хранилище
Хранилище профилей - пространство на DFS
Домен - Windows AD
Домен-контроллеры Windows 2019
Уровень домена - 2016
Посредством GPO настроено:

- Включение механизма автономных файлов
- назначение доступных вне сети Рабочего стола и Документов
- разрешение пользователю самостоятельно назначать папки для автономной работы

Касперский - Kaspersky Endpoint Security 11.6.0.394

До установки Касперского механизм отлично работает:

- файлы доступны вне сети
- при работе вне сети документы сохраняются на рабочий стол или Документы
- при появлении сети всё синхронизируется

Что происходит после установки Касперского:

- повторная попытка синхронизации останавливается на этапе "Ожидание синхронизации"
- попытка добавить произвольные файлы а режим "доступно вне сети" оканчиваются ошибкой "неизвестная функция"
- после того, как устройству дать сеть устройство по-прежнему находится в автономном режиме

Что пытался делать:

- добавлять папку %windir%/CSC в исключения
- включать/отключать компоненты защиты
- останавливать самого касперского

Есть ещё мысли?
Спасибо

Comment: *Есть ещё мысли?* Ну первая мысль - это тряхнуть техподдержку Каспера. не знаю как сейчас, но было время - общался по странным косякам с ними вполне вменяемо.

Comment: Это сделано, но
- они пока на меня молчат
- всегда полезно собрать несколько мнений

Comment: На всякий случай - а не установилась ли вместе с KES их секьюрная сеть? если да - попробуй пустить трафик синхронизации мимо этой сети (или вообще удалить этот компонент для начала).

Comment: @Akina, спасибо за совет, но KSN вообще отключен как компонент.